# How to troubleshoot deployment issues when running tests with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, deployment

In VisualStudio (2010 and 2012) :
is there an efficient way to troubleshoot deployment issues when using DeploymentItem attribute?
I currently must wait for test execution to realize that the items where not deployed. Also, when a path error occurs, it's painful to detect where the error stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All deployment errors are written in .trx file. Also items are deployed before test run in "out" folder.

Comment: Thanks. VS does not display those errors in its trx displayer. I did not think of looking into the trx with a text editor.